# Multiple SVG files export at multiple sizes (eg. png at 16px, 24px...)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export, png, multiple-sizes

I would like to know if there is any automated solution to export multiple SVG files (more than 200 icons) from Illustrator to multiple size PNG (16px, 24px, 32px, 48, px, 64px)

I know that there is Asset Export option to export one SVG to multiple assets at multiple size, but I have to do it one by one SVG. Reason I need this is, because I have more than 200 icons in separated SVG files, it will be painful to do it one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all of your icons as separate SVG files and all you need to do is convert them to PNGs at specific sizes, I would recommend IrfanView [(Download)](http://www.irfanview.com/).

Using Irfanview's batch conversion tools would make this a breeze. Steps:

- Select `File > Batch Conversion/Rename`
- Select `Batch Conversion - Rename results files`
- Set `Output Format` to `PNG - Portable Network Graphics`
- Set `Name Pattern` to `$N-16x16`. This will rename the batched files based on their original file name ($N) and then add the dimensions (-16x16)
- Check `Use advanced options` and then click `Advanced`

  - Check `RESIZE` and then select `Set New Size` and `Set one or both sides to` and set your desired width and height.
  - Go through the rest of the advanced settings to make sure you won't get any unexpected results.
  - Click `OK`
- Set your output directory.
- Add all of your icons into the list with the explorer window on the right side.
- Hit `Start Batch`
- Wait for it to finish and click `Return to Batch`.
- Change all the relevant settings to do your next size
- Repeat until finished.

As far as trying to do this automatically inside Illustrator, there's probably a script that someone's written or that can be written to loop through 200 files batch converting and exporting, but using IrfanView would probably be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

you could if you using the latest illustrator, you can go easily to Export > Export for Screens > then adjust you sizes or there are ios and Android  stander sizes.

Comment: I know that I can do that, but that is as I wrote, what I want to avoid. I have more that 200 separated SVG files, I have to open each one and export it to multiple size.
I need solution where I can import multiple SVG files, and as a result of export I will get PNG files in multiple sizes.